# How to store config in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've trying to store configuration variables for my Unity project. F.e. it could be DB connection string or, some connection variables.
When i'm trying to stire them in App.config i achieve error from unity:
ConfigurationManager is not defined.
When i solve this problem in VS, it stays at Unity.

Maybe there is another way to store such settings?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to change the settings at runtime, use a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) to store the settings.

If you want to change it, you need to use some kind of serialization such as json serialization and read/write your settings from a file. Keep in mind that you need to store the file in [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).